# Update pairs of columns based on pattern in their names

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is my dataframe:

```
col_1 <- c(1,2,NA,4,5)
temp_col_1 <-c(12,2,2,3,4)
col_2 <- c(1,23,423,NA,23)
temp_col_2 <-c(1,2,23,4,5)

df_test<-data.frame(col_1,temp_col_1,col_2, temp_col_2)
```

In column `col_1` I would like to replace `NA` with corresponding value from `temp_col_1` and do the same for `col_2` and `temp_col_2`

I know how to do it manually with `ifelse` statement, the problem is that I have tons of columns with pattern `col_name` and `temp_col_name` and I wonder how I can automate it.

I tried different things like `df_test[,paste('temp_','col_1`]', but nothing worked.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# list of columns we need to check for NA's
col.to.check <- colnames(df_test)[!grepl("^temp", colnames(df_test))]
# these columns need not be checked
col.to.keep <- colnames(df_test)[grepl("^temp", colnames(df_test))]

func <- function(x){ 
  y <- which(is.na(df_test[[x]]))       # which position do NA's exist
  z <- df_test[[paste0("temp_", x)]][y] # which to be used to replace
  df_test[[x]][y] = z                   # replace them
  return(df_test[[x]])
  }

df = data.frame(lapply(col.to.check, func))
colnames(df) = col.to.check
cbind(df, df_test[col.to.keep])

#  col_1 col_2 temp_col_1 temp_col_2
#1     1     1         12          1
#2     2    23          2          2
#3     2   423          2         23
#4     4     4          3          4
#5     5    23          4          5
```

Answer (score 2):

This should provide what you desire.

```
col_1 <- c(1,2,NA,4,5)
temp_col_1 <-c(12,2,2,3,4)
col_2 <- c(1,23,423,NA,23)
temp_col_2 <-c(1,2,23,4,5)

df_test<-data.frame(col_1,temp_col_1,col_2, temp_col_2)

temp_cols <- names(df_test)[grepl("^temp", names(df_test))]
cols <- sub("^temp_", "", temp_cols)

for (i in seq_along(temp_cols)){
  row_to_replace <- which(is.na(df_test[[cols[i]]]))
  df_test[[cols[i]]][row_to_replace] <- df_test[[temp_cols[i]]][row_to_replace]
}

df_test

  col_1 temp_col_1 col_2 temp_col_2
1     1         12     1          1
2     2          2    23          2
3     2          2   423         23
4     4          3     4          4
5     5          4    23          5
```

I'm having fun with this question.  The most compact approach I've come up with for it is:

```
lapply(names(df_test)[grepl("^temp_", names(df_test)],
       function(tc){
         col <- sub("^temp_", "", tc)
         row_to_replace <- which(is.na(df_test[[col]]))
         df_test[[col]][row_to_replace] <<- df_test[[tc]][row_to_replace]
       })
```

but it requires the use of the not-so-popular `<<-` operator.

Comment: with respect to the `lapply` solution,  even i had followed those steps and then was forced to use `assign()` to `.Globalenv` such as to reflect the changes made inside `lapply()`. even your `<<-` did the same. Could there be better ways than ours?

Comment: I think this is actually a spectacular case of where a `for` loop is the best option.  I was curious about this yesterday as well, and put together a gist for future reference. https://gist.github.com/nutterb/f05cc0e725ed389292116eb661f68bb5  I'm thinking about opening a new question with a larger data set to see if anyone can beat the speed of the `for` loop.

Comment: great! could `list2env()` help in this case?

Comment: I couldn't work out a way to make `list2env` useful.  but that might be a limitation of Benjamin.  I started a new question to pursue this further (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511191/optimizing-replacement-in-a-data-frame)  I'm curious to see what people smarter than me might come up with.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns come in pairs in a consistent order, like in your example, you could try:

**1a**

```
ix <- which(is.na(df_test), arr.ind = TRUE)
ix2 <- ix
ix2[ , 2] <- ix2[ , 2] + 1
df_test[ix] <- df_test[ix2]
```

Or:

**1b**

```
d1 <- df_test[ , c(TRUE, FALSE)]
d2 <- df_test[ , c(FALSE, TRUE)]
d1[is.na(d1)] <- d2[is.na(d1)]
d1
```

---

If you have pairs of columns, but not necessarily in arranged nicely pairwise as above, start by ordering the columns by their name:

```
df <- data.frame(temp_col_2, col_1, col_2, temp_col_1)
df <- df[ , order(names(df))]
```

**2a**

```
ix <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
ix2 <- ix
ix2[ , 2] <- ix2[ , 2] + ncol(df) / 2
df[ix] <- df[ix2]
```

Or:

**2b**

```
d1 <- df[ , 1:(ncol(df)/2)]
d2 <- df[ , (ncol(df)/2 + 1):ncol(df)]
```

Then proceed as in **1b**.

---

In general, I tend to think it is more convenient to work with data in a long format. Here's a possibility using `data.table` functions.

```
# melt data to long format
d <- melt(setDT(df_test), measure = patterns("^col", "^temp"), value.name = c("col", "temp"))

# update relevant values of 'col'
d[is.na(col), col := temp]

# if desired, cast back to wide format 
dcast(d, rowid(variable) ~ variable, value.var = c("col", "temp"))
```